# Как в WinForms сделать прозрачным PictureBox относительно своего родительского элемента?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня имеется форма одного цвета, кнопка другого цвета и `PictureBox` с `BackColor: Transparent`. У `PictureBox` прописан родительский элемент - кнопка. При запуске программы я наблюдаю, что фон у `PictureBox` цвета формы, а не родительского элемента - кнопки. Подскажите как исправить или куда копать, чтобы фон у `PictureBox` стал фоном кнопки.

[image]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Windows Forms не поддерживает прозрачность. Поэтому только на костылях, например относледоваться от PB и переопределить OnPaint, отрисовывать кнопку в битмап, вырезая из него кусок под себя и подкладывая под картинку. То есть написать свой собственный редрер PictureBox. Может есть способ хитрее, но я не практиковал. Вообще Winforms - это как бы не про красивые интерфейсы.

Comment: @aepot, если постараться, то поддерживает.

Comment: @Qwertiy о чем я и говорю, придется постараться. Я имел в виду поддержку нативного характера, ее нет.

Comment: Мне также было необходимо, чтобы цвет кнопки менялся при наведении. Вместе с этим должен был меняться и цвет фона у PictureBox. Поэтому я решил проблему через события. При наведении мыши на кнопку, менял фон кнопки и PictureBox. При покидании курсора мыши с кнопки, соответственно, менял фон у кнопки и PictureBox на другой.